# Why am I getting an error and crash code 0 after all was processed?

Tags: c++, boost

Hi I have a class for logging that uses boost and in the initLogging I have done this:

```
// Create a backend
boost::shared_ptr< SinkTextFileBakend > sink = boost::log::add_file_log(
    sm_folderOfLogFiles + "optimisations_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%N.log",
    boost::log::keywords::format = boost::log::expressions::stream
        << boost::log::expressions::attr< boost::log::attributes::current_process_name::value_type >("Executable") << "("
        << boost::log::expressions::attr< boost::log::attributes::current_process_id::value_type >("ExeUID") << ") CID("
        << correlid << ") " << severity << "["
        << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        << "] [" << boost::log::expressions::attr< boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
        << "] " << classname << " - " << boost::log::expressions::smessage,
    boost::log::keywords::open_mode = (std::ios::out | std::ios::app),
    boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 2 * 1024 * 1024,
    boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true
);

sink->locked_backend()->set_open_handler(&openingHandler);

boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(severity >= SeverityLevels::info);
boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

// for logging in console, too
boost::shared_ptr< boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend > backend =
    boost::make_shared< boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend >();
backend->add_stream(
    boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream >(&std::cout));

// Enable auto-flushing after each log record written
backend->auto_flush(true);

// Wrap it into the frontend and register in the core.
// The backend requires synchronization in the frontend.
boost::shared_ptr< boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink< boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend > > backend_sink(
    new boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink< boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend >(backend)); // for testing and printing log in sysout

backend_sink->set_formatter(
    boost::log::expressions::stream
    // line id will be written in hex, 8-digits, zero-filled
    << boost::log::expressions::attr< boost::log::attributes::current_process_name::value_type >("Executable")
    << "(" << boost::log::expressions::attr< boost::log::attributes::current_process_name::value_type >("ExeUID")
    << ") CID(" << correlid << ") " << severity << " ["
    << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    << "] [" << boost::log::expressions::attr< boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
    << "] " << classname << " - " << boost::log::expressions::smessage);
boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(backend_sink); // for testing and printing log in sysout
```

So I have 2 backends, one for writing in the file and the other for printing in the console. At the end of the execution I get an error like this:

```
*** Error in `/home/sop/project/build/proj': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000008caaa0 ***
*** Crashed with return code: 0 ***
```

(this in the IDE: KDevelop) or:

```
*** Error in `./proj': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000008caaa0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

(if run in terminal)

I have done some tests and if I remove the part of logging to console, then this problem disappears. If it has just the part for console logging it seems that I get the same error, so it seems that all the problem is in that part. I do not understand what am I doing wrong, any help please will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
backend->add_stream(
    boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream >(&std::cout));
```

`std::cout` is a global object and cannot be deleted with `operator delete`, which happens when `boost::shared_ptr` is destroyed. You should be using `boost::null_deleter`:

```
backend->add_stream(
    boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream >(&std::cout, boost::null_deleter()));
```